# How to find a quadrilateral where each side length is a distinct prime?

Tags: geometry

> Any tips for finding the vertices of a quadrilateral where each side length is a distinct prime?

I have tried to make the quadrilateral from Pythagorean triples but that did not work out so well.

Comment: Pythagorean triples always include an even term (which doesn't allow for different prime side lengths).  I would expect that most combinations of primes (that satisfy weak conditions like the triangle condition) would work.  What do you mean by "finding" the quadrilateral, what are you looking for?  The coordinates of its vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d$ be 4 primes that pair wise satisfy the tringle inequality.  Then by law of cosines we need $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta=c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\alpha $ or $\cos \alpha= \frac {a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2-2ab\cos\theta}{2cd} $ which, admittedly won't always have solutions but usually will (if pair wise the sides satisfy triangle inequality--- I think/hope) have multiple solutions.

Consider $7,13,11,17$

Then $\frac {7^2+13^2-11^3-17^2-2*7*13\cos \theta}{2*11*17}=$

$\frac {-192}{374}-\frac{182\cos\theta}{374}=$

$-.51337-.4866\cos \theta $ let theta be... 60 degrees (makes the cosine an easy 1/2)

Then we have $\alpha =\arccos( -.51337-.2433)=\arccos (-.7946)$.

So a quadrilateral with an angle of 60 between the sides 7 and 13 long and and angle of $\alpha $ between the sides 11 and 17, will be one of an infinite number of possibilities.

Set if one vertex is (0,0) another at (7,0) a third at (11cos (60),11sin (60)) and the fourth at ... well, just use trig.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that most triples of primes that satisfy the triangle inequality would work to create such a quadrilateral.  In particular, suppose that the sides of the triangle have lengths $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.  Then you need

\begin{align*}
A&\leq B+C+D\\
B&\leq A+C+D\\
C&\leq A+B+D\\
D&\leq A+B+C.
\end{align*}

For example, if you try $A=11$, $B=13$, $C=17$, and $D=19$, these four conditions hold.  We can pick two vertices of the quadrilateral, so let them be 
$(0,0)$ and $(11,0)$, with a distance of $11$ between them.

The other two vertices $(x,y)$ and $(w,z)$ satisfy the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2&=19^2\\
(w-11)^2+z^2&=17^2\\
(x-w)^2+(y-z)^2&=13^2
\end{align*}
If you solve this system of equations (which might not have a "nice") solution, you can get your quadrilateral.